# How to reject incoming connection using domain in TCP Wrapper?

Tags: linux, tcp

I am trying to configure TCP wrapper to deny access from ftp clietn. I want to use domain format syntax in client list of */etc/hosts.deny* as below. FTP service is the target daemon in my case.

```
vsftpd : .ywlocal.net
```

However, I have defined host name of ftp client(tester1) in `/etc/hosts` as below but vsftpd is still accepting the connection from the client.

```
127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
::1         localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6

192.168.11.17 tester1 tester1.ywlocal.net
```

I also have hostname of client in fqdn form.

```
[root@tester1 ~]# hostname
tester1.ywlocal.net
```

Where should I define the fqdn of client side to deny access from the ftp client?

Comment: I found reverse hostname lookup is working with */etc/hosts* . I checked this by no dns requests are sent to the dns server. However, I still cannot reject requests with *.ywlocal.net*